# changing the format from pdf to word (doc,docx) and viceversa in native php

Tags: php

I am trying to develop an api in php that will allow the users to convert their pdf files to docx and vice versa too. I searched and followed some links on stackoverflow but could not find any answers that allowed me to do it in native php. I want a solution in native php, I dont want to install any new library. I am new to php and english is not my first language, so pardon any mistakes.

Comment: Please show the code/method that you've came up with so far.

Comment: @JensHöpken  I am just starting my project.I meant is there any way to do it in native PHP or not.If  yes,then I wanted to know how

Comment: A *.docx file is basically a zipped file with some xml in it. When you rename a *.docx to *.zip you can have a look at it. *.pdf files are a little bit more complicated, but you can still create a (meaningfull) bytestream in php that represents a pdf file. But i would not recommend using php for a task like this. I even doubt that this is something a beginner should even start with such a complicated task. if you just want to get some experience you should try to convert a docx to html.